# importance of data structure to embedded software engineer

Tags: data-structures, embedded, embedded-linux

I  am an  embedded software engineer. I never have used data structures like trees, graphs, or linked lists. I have used only circular buffers, arrays, etc. I am curious to know in which part of embedded system data structures are trees, graphs, and linked lists used explicitly. Are there any specific examples?

Answer (score 7):

What data structures you use have little to do with *where* your software is running (i.e. microcontroller versus PC). It has more to do with *what* your software is doing.

The touch screen cash registers you see in fast food joints could be running entirely on a microcontroller. Or it could be a Windows apps (I've seen blue screens at McDonald's before).

That being said, structures like trees and graphs are often used in robotics to plan out routes and remember where they've been. 3D printers make extensive use of these structures and are often run in embedded environments. A PC will create various graphs of the slices of the object to be printed and then place them in a tree. The microcontroller in the printer then traverses the tree and prints the graphs.

Linked lists can be used in similar places to circular buffers or arrays (or stacks or queues) where a little more flexibility is desired. I've often seen them used in task scheduling algorithms. They could also be used in the aforementioned trees and graphs.

Comment: The widespread 3D printers running on small embedded processors (Arduino derivatives mostly) aren't doing much planning beyond acceleration profiling to execute a simple drip-fed list of G code instructions - what gets to the printer isn't really a tree any longer, even if it was generated on the PC by traversing one.

Comment: @kyel , thanks for your valuable reply. I have understood myself that I did have exposure to data structure .

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand what each particular data structures a good for - i.e. what particular data storage, organisation, or access problem each is intended to resolve.  Once you understand that for a selection of common data structures you will be equipped to recognize situations where one might be used to advantage.

It is likely that you have implemented systems using sub-optimal data structures either through lack of knowledge or experience or through the acceptability and simplicity of a sub-optimal solution. If for example an exhaustive search of a simple array meets performance requirements; because either the array is small enough, the processor fast enough or the real-time requirements permissive enough, then you might legitimately choose not to complicate things with a data structure more suited to efficient and deterministic search.  Not least because for example, debuggers are great at displaying array content, but not usually aware of higher-level data structures.

On the other hand it is likely that you have used other data structures than those you have mentioned, without perhaps realising it. Stacks(FILO), and Queues(FIFO) are prevalent in many embedded systems, I'd be surprised if you had not used them, even if they were ad-hoc implementations based on arrays.